Derived limit vs limit in the $\infty$ derived category
Fix an abelian category $A$ with enough projective objects. Denote by $D(A)_+$ bounded below derived category, it arises as a localization of a category of chain complexes of projective objects $Ch(Proj(A))_+$ in homotopy equivalences (as quasi isomorphism between two complexes of projective objects is a homotopy equivalence).
On the other hand the category $Ch(Proj(A))_+$ is naturally enriched in chain complexes: for any two objects $A_\bullet,B_\bullet\in Ch(Proj(A))_+$ one can form a complex $\underline{Hom}(A_\bullet,B_\bullet)$. Furthermore one can truncate $\underline{Hom}(A_\bullet,B_\bullet)$ so that it is concentrated in positive degrees, apply Dold Kan correspondence and view $Ch(Proj(A))_+$ as enriched in simplicial groups. Finally, using the fact that a simplicial group is a Kan complex, one can apply the homotopy coherent nerve and get an infinity category $D(A)_\infty$.
My question is: how can I relate notions from derived category such as (co)limits or tensor product to their infinity categorical analogs?
To be more concrete here is an example of what I would like to understand: I know what a derived functor of a sequential limit is. I have an idea about homotopy limit of (say) topological spaces $\lim (X_0 \xleftarrow{} X_1 \xleftarrow{} X_2...)$, one performs sequence of fibrant replacements to get the correct universal property. What is the relation between $Rlim$ and the limit in $D(A)_\infty$? I expect that "they are the same". Any general comments, examples and (possibly concise) references are appreciated.
By the way: don't we lose information when performing the truncation of a mapping complex $\underline{Hom}(A_\bullet,B_\bullet)$? Is $D(A)_\infty$ stable?

The two categories are the same. This is mainly addressed in Lurie's Higher Algebra, section 1.3.4, and the equivalence of these two categories is addressed in Thm 1.3.4.20 (along with Thm 1.3.3.14).

It is Theorem 1.3.4.4 in Higher Algebra by Lurie that your $D(A)_\infty$ is the underlying $\infty$-category of the model category $\mathrm{Ch}(A)_+$ (and hence that the $1$-categorical derived category $D(A)_+$ is the homotopy category of $D(A)_\infty$).
(Co)limits in $D(A)_\infty$ can therefore be computed as homotopy (co)limits in the model category: the homotopy (co)limit object is, when considered an object in the underlying $\infty$-category, also the (co)limit object in this $\infty$-category. For our case this is essentially Theorem 4.2.4.1 and Corollary 4.2.4.8 in Lurie's Higher Topos Theory.
The same holds for the derived tensor product: more generally, if $F\colon\mathcal{M}\to\mathcal{N}$ is a functor between model categories that preserves weak equivalences between cofibrant objects and $Q\colon\mathcal{M}\to\mathcal{M}$ is a cofibrant replacement functor, then the composite $FQ$ gives us a derived functor $\mathbf{L}F\colon\mathrm{Ho}\,\mathcal{M}\to\mathrm{Ho}\,\mathcal{N}$ between homotopy categories. But $FQ\colon\mathcal{M}\to\mathcal{N}$ preserves weak equivalences, so induces an underlying $\infty$-functor $(FQ)_\infty\colon\mathcal{M}_\infty\to\mathcal{N}_\infty$ on underlying $\infty$-categories by the universal property of the latter: they are defined as $\infty$-categorical localization of the model cateogries at the classes of weak equivalences. Since the homotopy categories of $\mathcal{M}_\infty$ and $\mathcal{N}_\infty$ are given by $\mathrm{Ho}\,\mathcal{M}$ and $\mathrm{Ho}\,\mathcal{N}$, we could suspect that the functor $\mathrm{Ho}\,(FQ)_\infty\colon \mathrm{Ho}\,\mathcal{M}\to \mathrm{Ho}\,\mathcal{N}$ that $(FQ)_\infty$ incudes on homotopy categories coincides with $\mathbf{L}F$. This is true, because the square
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\{\infty\text{-categories together with a subcategory}\} @>{\mathrm{localization}}>> \mathrm{Cat}_\infty\\
@V{\text{homotopy category}}VV @VV{\text{homotopy category}}V \\
\{\text{categories together with a subcategory}\} @>>{\text{localization}}>\mathrm{Cat}
\end{CD}
$$
of $\infty$-categories commutes, since all functors are left adjoint to inclusion functors and these right adjoints make their respective diagram commute.
It is true that $D(A)_\infty$ is stable, this is HA, Cor. 1.3.2.18.
